# Using OpenCV TLD from Python

Tags: python, opencv

According to the [release docs](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0-alpha.html) for OpenCV 3.0.0, it includes an implementation of the [Tracking-Detection-Learning](http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/tld.html) algorithm. There's even some [very basic docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/tracking/doc/tracker_algorithms.html) for the C++ code.

I downloaded and compiled the 3.0.0-beta, including the Python wrapper, and it seems to have succeeded, and although I can run the Python samples, I can't find any way to access and TLD functionality through the Python wrapper. I can't even find references to it in the code.

Is it actually included in the 3.0.0 release, and if so, how do I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tld c++ code for opencv3.0 is in the [opencv_contrib repo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/tracking),

unfortunately, atm  python or java wrapping is not ready yet.

Comment: well, it has python wrappers now, see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

From what I find so far there is no instruction, explicitly telling the user how to use TLD. But, you can access TLD tracking modules just by changing the parameter For instance: cv2.Tracker_create("TLD")

For a demo, you can try https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/samples/tracker.py and change the like cv2.Tracker_create("MIL") to cv2.Tracker_create("TLD")

Note: you must install opencv along with opencv_contrib to make this demo work.

Good Luck